# What is Regular expression to identify string literals in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, string-literals, javacc

I am trying to write parser for which i need to identify string literals, if my string starts and ends with ' (i.e single quote) then what will be the regular expression to identify string literal?

I'm using javacc for writing parser. can anybody help me with actual regular expression code in token format? i have tried enough on my own.

eg.

< INTEGER_VALUE : "0" | (["1"-"9"] (["0"-"9"])*) >

this is the token format to identify integer literal, I want same token format for string literal where string starts and end with single quote, I also tried using metacharacters (given in http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html tutorial)  but there were no successful results.

Comment: You need a parser, not a regular expression, unless you don't intend to permit escapes (e.g., \\) in your strings.

Comment: i am trying to write parser which needs to identify string literal as a token, i am also going to write interpreter for which I need my parser to identify string literals.

Comment: I have to disagree with chrylis. Regular expressions can express the syntax of strings for most languages.  See my answer for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using JavaCC.  The answer depends on the syntax of strings in your language.  Let's say any character is allowed in a string other than an apostrophe. I.e. a string consists of two apostrophes and any number (0 or more) of nonapostrophes in between.

```
<STRING: "'" (~["'"])* "'">
```

Now many languages don't allow newlines or returns in strings.  So here let's ban those too:

```
<STRING: "'" (~["'","\n","\r"])* "'">
```

Now the problem is: what if someone wants to put apostrophes, newlines or returns? Some languages (e.g. C) use backslashes as an escape, so let's say

- \'  means apostrophe
- \n  means newline
- \r  means return
- \\  means backslash
- \x  where x is any other character is considered an error

Here is the expression

```
<STRING: "'"  ("\\" ("\\" | "n" | "r" | "'") | ~["\\","\n","\r","'"] )* "'"
```

I.e. a string is two apostrophes with a sequence of 0 or more groups in between, where each group is either one of the two character sequences \\, \n, \r, \', or a character that is not a backslash, a newline, a return or an apostrophe.

Another approach is to use lexical states.

```
<DEFAULT> MORE: { "'" : INSTRING }
<INSTRING> MORE: { "\\\\" 
                 | "\\n" 
                 | "\\r"  
                 | "\\'"
                 | ~["\\","\n","\r","'"]
                 }
<INSTRING> TOKEN: { "'" : DEFAULT }
```

Comment: I should add that the two approaches here have different behavours when there is an error. The second gives a better indication of where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Not close enough, let's consider the following

```
// 'here is comment'
'is't correct string?'
```

where you have single quotes but it's not a string for sure. If you assure to strip out comments and that any in between quotes symbol will be escaped \' (like in most programming languages). I believe then everything will be just fine as in algorithm you described.

Comment: I have written logic for comment
< "//" (~[ "\n", "\r" ])*
    (
      "\n"
    | "\r"
    | "\r\n"
    ) >
| < "/*" (~[ "*" ])* "*"
    (
      ~[ "/" ] (~[ "*" ])* "*"
    )*
    "/" >

thats not what I want.
suppose there is a variable and string value is assigned to it, then i want to check if the string value (string literal) assigned to variable is according to my string pattern.

Comment: you written it wrong let's see following `'// is it comment?'`. I never use javacc but in bison you can easily deal with it using switching context. What I trying to say is that you do not deal with nested expressions

Comment: the one you mentioned above that is '// is it comment?' is valid string for my parser, i just need regular expression to prove it right, in javacc token format also it should take care of escape sequences like \n \r \t etc..

Comment: Guys thanks for help I got the close solution please let me know if it is correct one or not.

 < STRING_VALUE : "\'" (
           (~["'","\\","\n","\r"])
                |
                ("\\"
                    ( ["n","t","b","r","f","\\","'","\""])
         )
                    )*
              "\'" >

Comment: I think you've got it.